# Having more than one Get in Restful webservice

Tags: http, rest, get

I am working on a project to connect test instruments and get request and response from it using webservice.

I have to request more than one service from the instrument, but when I use more than two `@Get`s in the server, I get an error in my browser saying

> Cannot access WADL, please restart your restful webservice

This is my code,

```
GET 
@Produces("text/html") 
public String getHtml(){ 
   String ins_name=null; 

   try { 
      String [] env=null; 
      //setting the environment variable. 
      String[]callAndArgs= {"python","instrument_name.py"};//Python and file name 

      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(callAndArgs,env, 
         new java.io.File("C:\\fakepath\\NetBeansProjects\\DemoApp1\\build\\web"));//executing Python file 


      BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new   
      InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));//getting the value from Python file    
      BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new     
      InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));// reading the error     
      ins_name = stdInput.readLine();//reading the output from the Pythonfile     
      System.out.println(ins_name); 
   } 
   catch (IOException e) {//catching the exception 

      System.out.println("exception occured"); 
      e.printStackTrace(); 
      System.exit(-1); 
   } 


   return ins_name;//returning the instrument name 
} 

@GET 
@Produces("text/html") 
public String getHtml1() { 
   String check=null; 
   String c1="hjhj"; 
   String [] env=null; 
   //setting the environment variable. 
   try{ 
      String[] callAndArgs= {"python","check_connection.py",c1};//Python and file name 

      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(callAndArgs,env, 
      new java.io.File("C:\\Users\\Balkishore\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\DemoApp1\\build\\web"));//executing Python file 


      BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
      InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));//getting the value from Python file 

      BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
         InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));// reading the error 

      check= stdInput.readLine();//reading the output from the Python file 
      System.out.println(); 
   } 
   catch (IOException e) {//catching the exception 

      System.out.println("exception occured"); 
      e.printStackTrace(); 
      System.exit(-1); 
   } 
   return check; 
} 

/** 
* Web service operation 

} 

/** 
* PUT method for updating or creating an instance of GenericResource 
* @param content representation for the resource 
* @return an HTTP response with content of the updated or created resource. 
*/ 
@PUT 
@Consumes("text/html") 
public String putHtml(String interface_name) { 

   try { 
      String [] env=null; 
      String [] callAndArgs= {"python","connection.py",this.interface_name=interface_name};//Python file with arguments 

      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(callAndArgs,env, 
         new java.io.File("C:\\fakepath\\NetBeansProjects\\DemoApp1\\build\\web"));//executing the Python file 



      BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new  
         InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));//getting the input 


      BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
         InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));//getting the error 


      interface_name = stdInput.readLine();//reading the output 
      System.out.println(interface_name); 
   } 
   catch (IOException e) {//catching the exception  
      System.out.println("exception occured"); 
      e.printStackTrace(); 
      System.exit(-1); 

   } 
   return interface_name; 
} 
}
```

I have also attached the image of the error message.

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 1):

You can't define distinct "GET" for a resource unless you specify distinct Path for your methods  @Path("/mypath") in addition to your resource path

```
@Path("/myRes")
public class myResource{

   @GET @Path("/myAttr")
   public void getAttr(...)
}
```

Comment: first of all thank you very much for the reply. Please excuse my stupidity as i am very much new to java and netbeans, i couldn't get what you meant there? i tried creating a new path under html1 but i am getting the same error again.

Comment: Do you use some client library  to consume your service ?